# set http only and secure flag for cookies in lighttpd

Tags: linux, security, cookies, lighttpd, httponly

We are using `lighttpd` web server in our code base. It is that we need to add `SECURE` and `HTTP ONLY` flags for the `cookie`.

I have gone through many examples but all are related to  PHP and some other kanguage. We don't use PHP in our code. Is there anyway that I can get this? Can anything be done in the .conf file like in `apache` web server.

I have tested apache web server by adding changes in the httpd.conf and checked the packet capture. It worked. But unable to achieve this in lighttpd.

We use `C language` in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Well, To answer my own question.

There is nothing to do with the lighttpd.conf as of httpd.conf for apache.

We are setting the cookie header in a lua file(Kepler). Appending secure to that cookie header fixed the issue.